# error CS0103: The name 'txtReferralCode' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm about ready to pull my hair out over this. I'm working on an ASP.NET 2.0 website in VS2010 and I'm getting the error you see in the title. The error only appears when I attempt to publish the website. If I simply right click the aspx file that it's in and click "View in Browser" it works perfectly fine. It also works fine if I run the file in debug mode from VS2010. There are other asp controls in the code that work perfectly fine, but for whatever reason, the one I've added has a problem.

Here's some of the relevant code:

c#:

```
public partial class ApplicationScreen1Hold : System.Web.UI.Page
{
....
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ....
         if (Request.QueryString["SID"] != null) //this is existing code
         {
             hdnSID.Value =  Request.QueryString["SID"].ToString().Trim();
          }
         if (Request.QueryString["RID"] != null) //this is my new code
         {
             txtReferralCode.Text = Request.QueryString["RID"];
         }
    ....
    }
}
```

html:

```
<td style="padding-left:25px">
    <label>Referral Code
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtReferralCode" runat="server" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
    </label>
</td>
```

In the c# code, I left in the line above to show how one of the other inputs in the same form is accessed with no issues. The text box control in the html I had copies from another text box on the page and changed the `id` and removed the `class` and `onkeyup` event as they weren't needed.

Is it possible I need to define the text box and I've just not found the where it does it for other controls or am I likely missing something else?

I've looked at the other questions which have referenced this error code but none of them have been able to help me.

Comment: Is there a designer file associated with this page?  You might check that it has the control defined.

Comment: There is no designer file. If that were it I'd've solved this a while ago as that seems to be the go to answer for this sort of thing. I've found no way to create one either.

Comment: OK, so this happens during the compile for the publication process, rather than after deployment when you test the site?

Comment: That's correct. I should close this now though because while I'm not sure what specifically caused this, I updated the html page to the most recent on the SVN that we had and migrated my changes to it and it worked. My specific problem ended up being that I wasn't using the most current version of the page. I didn't make the last set of changes to that page however so I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete designer file associated with your *.aspx file. Right click  *.aspx file and click "convert to web application". It will create a  designer file thats  *.aspx.designer.cs and this file must include all the controls you used in your .aspx file.
Make sure you use right namepsace thats *.aspx.designer.cs and *.aspx.cs controls are in the same namespace..

Comment: Thank you for your time but as I mentioned in a comment on the initial post there was no designer file to delete.

Comment: Hey, it seems that u use label as xml tag. I think your label tag must include this asp: prefix. thats 
<asp:Label ...